# Compare two different time range in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hi everyone I'm amateur in VB.net. Most of you already help me in one n another way on some different topics.

Currently I'm trying to compare two different time range. I want to do so one time range can't overlap the second time range.

Suppose one time range is `06-Aug-2016 11:20 to 07-Aug-2016 15:30`
Second time range is `06-Aug-2016 16:00 to 06-Aug-2016 22:00`

So when we compare the range we get false result that this time range is already booked.

Comment: You do it exactly as you would expect to. You check whether the start of one range is after the end of the other or the start of the other is after the end of the one.  You write the code you think it should be and, if it doesn't work, THEN you post here, showing us what you've done and explaining exactly how it doesn't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is any clash, you only have to compare the *EndDate* of the 1st set to the *StartDate* of the 2nd input.

```
    Dim StartDate1 As Date
    Dim EndDate1 As Date
    Dim StartDate2 As Date
    Dim EndDate2 As Date


        StartDate1 = "06-Aug-2016 11:20"
        EndDate1 = "07-Aug-2016 15:30"
        StartDate2 = "07-Aug-2016 16:00"
        EndDate2 = "06-Aug-2016 22:00"

        If StartDate2 < EndDate1 Then
            MsgBox("Clash")
        End If
```